# Как создать список списков переборов чисел от 1 до k?(без повторений)

Tags: python, список, перебор

(В моем случае k=4)
Есть список n, с 4(k) элементами, каждый из которых задается рандомно от 1 до 4(k), при этом ни одно число не должно повторяться...
Теперь есть список N, в который мы хотим вставить список n, при этом также ни один список n не должен повторяться...
Т.к. я не знаю (лень считать) итоговое кол-во списков n, то через for все прогоняем
(За 100000 прогонов, думаю, слишком маленькая вероятность пропустить хотя бы одну комбинацию)

Код:

```
import random
N=[]
n=[]
for i in range(0,100000):
    n.clear()
    while len(n)!=4:
        x=random.randint(1,4)
        if n.count(x)==0:
            n.append(x)
    if N.count(n)==0:
        N.append(n)
print(len(N),N)
```

Проблема в том, что мне выводится какой-то бред:
"1 [[*любая комбинация из 1,2,3,4*]]"
Если print'ов наставить в коде, то становится понятно, что список n перебирается, один раз даже добавляется в N, но дальше ни-ни... А потом каким-то чудом список N чистится, но оставляет один пустой список внутри себя...

Comment: ```n.clear()``` уберите

Comment: @AndrewHolovko тогда список n не будет перезаписываться, и тогда цикл будет вечно один и тот же список n крутить

Comment: Можно сделать генерацию случайной последовательности чисел без ```n.count(x)==0``` и цикла (т.к. в худшем случае вы можете очень долго пытаться подобрать "недостающее число" (при k = 1000+, например). Создаёте массив, содержащий все элементы от 1 до k: ```r = [x for x in range(1,k)]```, затем вытаскиваете из этого массива элементы с помощью ```random.choise(r)```, удаляя вытащенный элемент из r и добавляя его в x. Так делаете, пока ```len(r) != 0```. Profit!

Comment: "Т.к. я не знаю (лень считать) итоговое кол-во списков" (c) — `k!`. Для 4 это `4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24`. А если будет 6 или 7 - можете не дождаться, пока оно там будет перебирать)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените `n.clear()` на `n = []`.

Когда вы делаете `N.append(n)` - вы добавляете объект (`n`) в список. И когда делаете `n.clear()` - он чистит объект `n`.

По этому у вас и результат соответствующий. Проверено.

Comment: Почему так? Если я сначала добавляю в N, n, и только потом его очищаю?

Comment: В питоне есть встроенный метод id(), если в него передать объект, он вернёт его ссылку на объект. Посмотри айди n и последнего элемента N. ID будут идентичны.

Comment: То есть грубо говоря ты запихнул объект, а не его значение.

Comment: Понял, спасибо )

Comment: @Rurik `n = []` создаёт новый объект, а у вас получается ссылка на один и тот же объект добавляется в список.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется вы усложняете задачу прогоном 100000. И чем больше k, тем больше вероятность, что вы получите неверный результат, да и долго это. Лучше сначала создать перестановки, а потом их перемешать.

```py
from itertools import permutations
import random

k = 4
*a, = permutations(range(1,k+1), k)
random.shuffle(a)
print(len(a),a)
```